# How to mock inner call to pyspark sql function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mocking, python-unittest

Got the following piece of pyspark code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

null_or_unknown_count = df.sample(0.01).filter(
    F.col('env').isNull() | (F.col('env') == 'Unknown')
).count()
```

In test code, the data frame is mocked, so I am trying to set the return_value for this call like this:

```
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import ANY

@mock.patch('pyspark.sql.DataFrame', spec=pyspark.sql.DataFrame)
def test_null_or_unknown_validation(self, mock_df):
    mock_df.sample(0.01).filter(ANY).count.return_value = 250
```

But this fails with the following:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 44, in _
  jc = getattr(sc._jvm.functions, name)(col._jc if isinstance(col, Column) else col)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

Also tried `mock_df.sample().filter().count.return_value = 250`, which gives the same error.

How do I mock the filter i.e. `F.col('env').isNull() | (F.col('env') == 'Unknown')` correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to my smart colleague at work, here is the answer. We have to mock `pyspark.sql.functions.col` and then set a return_value.

```
@mock.patch('pyspark.sql.functions.col')
@mock.patch('pyspark.sql.DataFrame', spec=pyspark.sql.DataFrame)
def test_null_or_unknown_validation(self, mock_df, mock_functions):
    mock_functions.isNull.return_value = True # (or False also works)
    mock_df.sample(0.01).filter(ANY).count.return_value = 250
```

Using `mock_df.sample().filter().count.return_value = 250` also works fine.